# SharePoint REST API for Sharepoint online retrieving items from a list/document library which exceeds 5000 items

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have SP online list/document libraries which are going to exceed 5000 items threshold limit. I have created index columns.

Question: I have a custom form, where I will retrieve the data from the list to show up on the form. Will the rest API I am having will work or do I need to take care of anything else.

```js
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('ABC').items.filter("ReqID eq '" + UniqueID +'").orderById("ID").get().then(function() {
```

Can you please advise

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

This is list view threshold issue. For sharepoint online, you can Index Columns Used as View Filters:

- https://natechamberlain.com/2018/05/21/how-to-resolve-sharepoint-list-view-threshold-error-the-view-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold/

Or you can make use of other pnp js methods:

- [Get Paged Items](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#get-paged-items)
- [Get All Items](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#get-all-items)

[image]

```
// we can also use filter as a supported odata operation, but this will likely fail on large lists
const allItems: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("BigList").items.select("Title").filter("Title eq 'Test'").getAll();
console.log(allItems.length);
```

BR